# Add square brackets at beginning and end of json file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON file and I want to add a square bracket at the beginning and end of JSON.
eg.
Input

```
{
"name": "Ram",
"age": 25
},
{
"name": "Laxman",
"age": 24
}
```

Expected output:

```
[
{
"name": "Ram",
"age": 25
},
{
"name": "Laxman",
"age": 24
}
]
```

this is a sample response, I am having a large JSON data in a file.

Comment: Inputs are `Objects`, push them into an array.

Comment: @RoguSmith objects are in a JSON file, How can I iterate the objects. could you please explain with an example?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, you can not have two objects on top level

Comment: @RoguSmith We should consider that the JSON is valid in the file; it is simply that an example was needed. I could be wrong, so OP should check that.

Also OP, there are a few libraries out there for pushing JSON into an array or dictionary, so try looking into one of those.

Comment: Try this package npm i file-get-contents

Answer (score 0):

The best option (in my opinion) would be to open a new reader;

- Open a BufferedReader
- Append `[`
- Append JSON file
- Append `]`

From there you can use the BufferedReader or write it into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

So, we need to consider 2 situations here:

The first one is when you're responsible for creating this input file. Then, assuming you already have those objects in an array and just need to save the array itself instead of the individual objects using a for.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const objs = [ { "name": "Ram","age": 25},{ "name": "Laxman","age": 24} ]
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(objs)

fs.writeFile("inputFile.json", jsonData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

---

The second situation if when you don't have control to modify the input file in its creation, and are just transforming the file previously saved. In this case you'll  need to completely rewrite the file due to `fs` limitations for positional "inserts". To do so, read the previous file into a buffer, prepend it with the opening bracket "[" and append the closing one "]" at the end. As follows:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const filename = 'inputFile.json'

const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filename)
const newBuffer = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('['), fileBuffer, Buffer.from(']')])
fs.writeFileSync(filename, newBuffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after hours of searching, I found nothing so I wrote a custom code that works like a charm. Hope it helps!:)

```
const fs = require('fs')
var response = {};

const fsOps = async (params) => {

    try {
        const path = "tmp/" + params.user + ".json";
        const data = params.data;
        const chunksNumber = params.chunksNumber;
        var chunkID = params.chunkID;

        //ON FIRST CHUNK ADD [ 
        if (chunkID === 1) {
            fs.appendFile(
                path, ("["), 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );
            if (chunksNumber !== 1)
                fs.appendFile(
                    path, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + ',', 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    }
                );
        }

        //WRITE CHUNKS
        if (chunkID !== 1 && chunkID < chunksNumber) {
            fs.appendFile(
                path, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + ',', 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );
        }

        //ON LAST CHUNK WRITE THE LAST CHUNK AND ADD ]
        if (chunkID === chunksNumber) {
            console.log("LAST CHUNK")
            fs.appendFile(
                path, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );

            //APPEND ] on the end of file
            fs.appendFile(
                path, ("]"), 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );

            //READ THE FILE
            fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    return;
                } else {
                    response = data;
                }
            })

            //DELETE FILE
            fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    return err
                }
            })
        }
        //Return object with all the part data
        return JSON.parse(response);

    } catch (err) {
        //IN CASE OF ERROR DELETE FILE
        fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return err
            }
        })
        return err;
    }
}

module.exports = fsOps;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).